# Setting up Tor relay and port reachability test failed error message

Tags: relays, configuration, windows, onion-routing, vidalia

Greeting earthlings,

I am attempting to set up Tor relay and the only issue I am encountering is a message stating that Server Port Reachability test failed and directory port reachability test failed.

Specific Error Message 1:
Server Port Reachability Test Failed:
Your relays server port is not reachable by other Tor clients. This can happen if you are behind a router or firewall that requires you to set up port forwarding. If "IP address" is not your correct IP address and server port, please check your relays configuration.

Specific Error Message 2:
Directory Port Reachability Test Failed
Your Relays directory port is not reachable by other Tor clients. This can happen if you are behind a router or firwall that requires you to set up port forwarding. If "IP address" is not your correct IP address and directory port, please check your relays configuration.

Within Vidalia the relay port is 443 and the directory port is 9030. I have checked my firewall and Tor and Vidalia are allowed full access so Vidalia trying to establish a circuit (with no sucess at this time) and Tor is connecting fine. The network setup is a the internet connection coming into a cisco modem (this is the public IP address Tor is seeing). After the modem the internet connection is connected to a router which distributes addresses to computing devices via DHCP, the computer I am attempting to use  as a Tor relay is one of the connections on the router which is in turn fed to the modem.

Within the Cisco Router Setup/ Configuration Ftp, Telnet, SMTP, DNS, TFTP, Finger, HTTP, pop3, NNMP, SMNP AND pptp protocols are allowed to be forwared to IP address that the Cisco Router router assigns (i.e. my computer). The thing with forwarding the aforementioned ports in router configuration is that the router does not allow one to choose a port at all when forwarding the protocol, this indicates default ports associated with those services seem to be programmed by default and not changable when forwarding for the router. For the protocols UDP and TCP I am allowed to specify any port but again only for those two protocols.

Please correct me if I am wrong but the only way I see Vidalia working as a relay correclty based on the parameters is if:

1. Ports 443 and 9030 are either TCP or UDP ( I tied forwarding both ports using those protocols and changing from DHCP to Static address configuration to no avail)
2. Having the Vidalia use one of the default standard ports to include FTP, Telnet, SMTP, DNS, TFTP, Finger, HTTP, pop3, NNMP, smnp OR pptp for forwarding but only using the default ports normally associated with those protocols and no other as this seemd to be programmed as a default security feature into the router.

If anyone knows what protocols are being used in Vidalia for ports 443 (Error 1 port) and 9030 ( Error 2 Port) it will help in further troubleshooting. I can buy another router/ trade in the current one for one that will allow forwarding of all protocols to any port specifed as a last resort.

Comment: I did some more trouble shooting and now have the relay node set up and running. I am going to tweak a few more things before posting my fix for this, no new hardware needed.

Comment: Could you explain how you solved it? I am having the same problem.